# How to use sessions in iframe src

Tags: php, session-cookies

i have a webpage i would like to display in an iframe. This webpage stores session variables when opened using `session_start()`, the sessions work well when i open with browser but not in the iFrame. How can i solve this.
I tried `header('p3p: cp= "cura ADMa DEVa Psao psdo We bus UNI PUR INT DEM STA PRE COM NAV OTC NOI DSP COR");` but that didn't work, even displayed `internal server error`.

Is it possible to display a page that uses `sessions` in an iframe?

Comment: That should be possible. What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Does your server error log have any entries for the internal server error? It is definitely possible to use sessions in an iframe. Maybe a CORS related issue?

Comment: If the main document is from a different domain - then the problem is likely simply the fact, that 3rd-party cookies often get blocked for privacy reasons.

Comment: _"but that didn't work, even displayed internal server error."_ - then go check what the error log has to say, instead of wailing about it here.

Comment: But I don't suppose such a policy will have much effect any more these days - if it did, then all the "bad" tracker people would also use it. Depending on what the session is used for, resp. how "secure" the whole thing needs to be, you might rather consider switching to passing the session ID via GET/POST parameters, than via cookie.